# add_endRequest is not firing after HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am exporting CSV when the user clicks on button in update panel. But so to do this i used the below script to show the Progress Bar

```
var updateProgress = null;
function postbackButtonClick() 
{
    updateProgress = $find("<%= UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>");
    window.setTimeout("updateProgress.set_visible(true)", updateProgress.get_displayAfter());
    return true;
}

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function hideProgressBar() 
{   
    $("#MainContent_UpdateProgress1").hide();                    
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) 
{
    alert('End Request Handler');
    if (args.get_error() != undefined) 
    {
        var errorMessage = args.get_error().message;
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
}

function appl_init() 
{
    var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    pgRegMgr.add_beginRequest(postbackButtonClick);
    pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(hideProgressBar);
}
```

My HTML CODE

```
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatepanelDropDownTaskType"
        class="Token-setup-popup">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div id="loading" class="loading">
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgBusyIndicator" ImageUrl="~/images/busy-indicator.gif" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanelDropDownTaskType" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
 <p style="text-align:right">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export To CSV" OnClick="btnExport_Click" OnClientClick="return postbackButtonClick()" ></asp:LinkButton>

            </p>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in my code behind i am using

```
HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
Response.ContentType = FileType;
Response.Write(content);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

because of the above code i am not able to fire the EndRequestHandler method. Any suggestions to resolve this issue

Comment: EndRequest will be triggered for partial post while using updatepanel and if you are exporting it requires full post so end request wont get trigger. Could you please show your html part

Comment: Hi Sridhar i updated my code... so how do i achieve this?